# Sitecore Rule based Personalization

Tags: personalization

We are using Sitecore 9.0 Update 2 in PAAS and trying to implement Rule based Personalization based on date time . I am able to configure the rule but it is not getting executed and not showing any difference on website

Is there any setting which i need to enable in Sitecore 9.0 Update 2 in PAAS to get this working

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the Personalization rule you created? also do you have output cache set on that rendering?